# Japanese term for backwards

Tags: english-to-japanese

It is easy to find **inside out** in a dictionary: 裏返し{うらがえし}, but I have difficulty translating **backwards** in the expression

> to put a T-shirt on backwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can use 前後ろ for "backwards" or "front-to-back". For example,

> Tシャツを前後ろに着る

*Edit.* [People in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35182478#35182478) also point out that there is also 後ろ前 "back-to-front", so

> 前後ろ ↔ 前が後ろ "front to back"
>   後ろ前 ↔ 後ろが前 "back to front"

Comment: I became slightly curious about which is used most, Google Trends shows no big difference though: https://www.google.com/trends/explore?geo=JP&q=前後ろ,後ろ前

Comment: @KessVargavind The data is so similar, it's hard to believe that it really tracks the *word* 前後ろ and not sentence (or search queries) just using 前 and 後ろ in this order (or in any order). For comparison, the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese has 前後ろ 9 results and 後ろ前 19 results. With these low numbers, it's hard to call it a trend, though.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I am not able to get Google Trends to compare exactly what I write. I did try to enclose the search words with quotation marks, but it seems to have no effect, in contrast to normal Google searches.

Comment: The expressions「後ろと前逆」「前と後ろ逆」「後ろ前逆」
with 「逆」 to emphasize the backward-ness are very commonly used.  Enter in google search image and you will get the images you want with a lot of backwards shirts.  Enter  前が後ろ and it doesn't work.  (I think you should add this to your answer).